# Prime numbers of the form $ n^{34} -9$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For what positive integer values of $n$ where $n^{34}-9$ is a prime.

I am not getting how to approach this one.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.  So, $n^{34}-9 = (n^{17})^2-3^2=\dots$ and this is definitely *not* prime for...

Comment: sorry it was very trivial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$n^{34}-9=(n^{17}+3)(n^{17}-3)$ so it is never prime as there is no value of $n$ that makes one of the factors $1$.